# Error: Bad File Descriptor Error Socket Programming

Tags: sockets, networking, boost

I am trying to write a multi client Pub/Sub model using Boost Asio(version 1_67_0) on Ubuntu 18.0.

I am able to connect my client to server and publish data with localhost but after data being published on server I get "Bad File Descriptor" error.

Server Code: https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_server.cpp

Client Code:
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp

Please, help me with the error.

Error:

```
[server] client_id    : cid1
[server] username     : none
[server] password     : none
[server] clean_session: true
[server] keep_alive   : 1
[server]subscribe received. packet_id: 1
[server] topic_filter: mqtt_client_cpp/topic1 qos: at_most_once
[server]subscribe received. packet_id: 2
[server] topic_filter: mqtt_client_cpp/topic2_1 qos: at_least_once
[server] topic_filter: mqtt_client_cpp/topic2_2 qos: exactly_once
[server] publish received. dup: no qos: at_most_once retain: no
[server] topic_name: mqtt_client_cpp/topic1
[server] contents: test1
[server] publish received. dup: no qos: at_least_once retain: no
[server] packet_id: 1
[server] topic_name: mqtt_client_cpp/topic2_1
[server] contents: test2_1
[server] publish received. dup: no qos: exactly_once retain: no
[server] packet_id: 2
[server] topic_name: mqtt_client_cpp/topic2_2
[server] contents: test2_2
[server] puback received. packet_id: 1
[server] pubrec received. packet_id: 2
[server] pubrel received. packet_id: 2
[server] pubcomp received. packet_id: 2
[server] disconnect received.
[server] error: Bad file descriptor
```

Server Code:

```
    inline void close_proc(std::set<con_sp_t>& cons, mi_sub_con& subs, con_sp_t const& con) {
        cons.erase(con);
    
        auto& idx = subs.get<tag_con>();
        auto r = idx.equal_range(con);
        idx.erase(r.first, r.second);
    }
       

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cout << argv[0] << " port" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    
        MQTT_NS::setup_log();
    
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    
        auto s = MQTT_NS::server<>(
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),
                boost::lexical_cast<std::uint16_t>(argv[1])
            ),
            ioc
        );
    
        s.set_error_handler(
            [](MQTT_NS::error_code ec) {
                std::cout << "error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }
        );
    
        std::set<con_sp_t> connections;
        mi_sub_con subs;
    
        s.set_accept_handler(
            [&connections, &subs](con_sp_t spep) {
                auto& ep = *spep;
                std::weak_ptr<con_t> wp(spep);
    
                using packet_id_t = typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ep)>::packet_id_t;
                std::cout << "accept" << std::endl;
    
                // Pass spep to keep lifetime.
                // It makes sure wp.lock() never return nullptr in the handlers below
                // including close_handler and error_handler.
                ep.start_session(std::move(spep));
    
                // set connection (lower than MQTT) level handlers
                ep.set_close_handler(
                    [&connections, &subs, wp]
                    (){
                        std::cout << "[server] closed." << std::endl;
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        close_proc(connections, subs, sp);
                    });
                ep.set_error_handler(
                    [&connections, &subs, wp]
                    (MQTT_NS::error_code ec){
                        std::cout << "[server] error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        close_proc(connections, subs, sp);
                    });
    
                // set MQTT level handlers
                ep.set_connect_handler(
                    [&connections, wp]
                    (MQTT_NS::buffer client_id,
                     MQTT_NS::optional<MQTT_NS::buffer> username,
                     MQTT_NS::optional<MQTT_NS::buffer> password,
                     MQTT_NS::optional<MQTT_NS::will>,
                     bool clean_session,
                     std::uint16_t keep_alive) {
                        using namespace MQTT_NS::literals;
                        std::cout << "[server] client_id    : " << client_id << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] username     : " << (username ? username.value() : "none"_mb) << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] password     : " << (password ? password.value() : "none"_mb) << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] clean_session: " << std::boolalpha << clean_session << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] keep_alive   : " << keep_alive << std::endl;
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        connections.insert(sp);
                        sp->connack(false, MQTT_NS::connect_return_code::accepted);
                        return true;
                    }
                );
                ep.set_disconnect_handler(
                    [&connections, &subs, wp]
                    (){
                        std::cout << "[server] disconnect received." << std::endl;
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        close_proc(connections, subs, sp);
                    });
                ep.set_puback_handler(
                    []
                    (packet_id_t packet_id){
                        std::cout << "[server] puback received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        return true;
                    });
                ep.set_pubrec_handler(
                    []
                    (packet_id_t packet_id){
                        std::cout << "[server] pubrec received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        return true;
                    });
                ep.set_pubrel_handler(
                    []
                    (packet_id_t packet_id){
                        std::cout << "[server] pubrel received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        return true;
                    });
                ep.set_pubcomp_handler(
                    []
                    (packet_id_t packet_id){
                        std::cout << "[server] pubcomp received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        return true;
                    });
                ep.set_publish_handler(
                    [&subs]
                    (MQTT_NS::optional<packet_id_t> packet_id,
                     MQTT_NS::publish_options pubopts,
                     MQTT_NS::buffer topic_name,
                     MQTT_NS::buffer contents){
                        std::cout << "[server] publish received."
                                  << " dup: "    << pubopts.get_dup()
                                  << " qos: "    << pubopts.get_qos()
                                  << " retain: " << pubopts.get_retain() << std::endl;
                        if (packet_id)
                            std::cout << "[server] packet_id: " << *packet_id << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] topic_name: " << topic_name << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "[server] contents: " << contents << std::endl;
                        auto const& idx = subs.get<tag_topic>();
                        auto r = idx.equal_range(topic_name);
                        for (; r.first != r.second; ++r.first) {
                            r.first->con->publish(
                                topic_name,
                                contents,
                                std::min(r.first->qos_value, pubopts.get_qos())
                            );
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                ep.set_subscribe_handler(
                    [&subs, wp]
                    (packet_id_t packet_id,
                     std::vector<MQTT_NS::subscribe_entry> entries) {
                        std::cout << "[server]subscribe received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        std::vector<MQTT_NS::suback_return_code> res;
                        res.reserve(entries.size());
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        for (auto const& e : entries) {
                            std::cout << "[server] topic_filter: " << e.topic_filter  << " qos: " << e.subopts.get_qos() << std::endl;
                            res.emplace_back(MQTT_NS::qos_to_suback_return_code(e.subopts.get_qos()));
                            subs.emplace(std::move(e.topic_filter), sp, e.subopts.get_qos());
                        }
                        sp->suback(packet_id, res);
                        return true;
                    }
                );
                ep.set_unsubscribe_handler(
                    [&subs, wp]
                    (packet_id_t packet_id,
                     std::vector<MQTT_NS::unsubscribe_entry> entries) {
                        std::cout << "[server]unsubscribe received. packet_id: " << packet_id << std::endl;
                        for (auto const& e : entries) {
                            subs.erase(e.topic_filter);
                        }
                        auto sp = wp.lock();
                        BOOST_ASSERT(sp);
                        sp->unsuback(packet_id);
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    
        s.listen();
    
        ioc.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the client disconnects the connection.

The client publishes 3 times. The publish messages's qos are 0, 1, and 2.
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp#L96-L102

This is the lambda expression that disconnects the connection if **5** times called.
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp#L31-L33

The lambda expression is called from the following points:

### 1

The client receives puback from the server. This is the response of QoS1 publish.
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp#L73

### 2

The client receives pubcomp from the server. This is the final response of QoS2 publish.
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp#L86

### 3, 4, and 5

The server echo backs the published message. This is echo backed publish message handler. The client publishes 3 times so the echo backed publish handler is called 3 times.
https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp/blob/master/example/no_tls_client.cpp#L119

So the lambda expression called 5 times then the client sends disconnect packet to the server. When the server receives the disconnect message, the server removes the connection. As the result of the removal, the server no longer receives the message.

```
[server] error: Bad file descriptor
```

This is a typical error code in this case.

If you want to continue the connection, just remove the disconnect lambda expression call from the client.